# NETLOGO: Iterate over agents with a variable set on a slider

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to iterate over agents to change them randomly.

Basically there ar "n" number of coins (n is defined by a slider that creates those n number of agents)

The function to change them that I'm trying is the following

```
to tossing
  if any? coins with [color = white] [   
    ask coins [
      let coin-toss random-float 1.0
      if coin-toss > 0.5 [
        print "hi"
        ;set shape "coin tails"
        set color lime
        set flip 1
      ]
      if coin-toss < 0.5 [
         set color pink
         set flip 0
      ]
    ]
  ]
  if not any? coins with [color = white] [
    ask coins [
      set color white
      set flip 3
    ]
  ]
  
end
```

This doesn't even change the colors, and I'm sure it won't change each coin differently.
I've been searching how to approach this but can't find a thing.

Edited solution and adding previous procedure:

```
to go
  ifelse (any? turtles with [color = red]) [   
    print "red"
    restart
    ;ask coins [ tossing ]
  ]
  [
    ask one-of cryptographers [ update ]
    wait 0.6
    ask coins [ tossing ]
    ;recolor
  ]
  tick
end

to tossing
  if any? coins with [shape = "circle"] [   
    ask coins [
      ;let a random-float 1
      ifelse (flip = 3) and (random-float 1 > 0.5) [
        ;print "hi"
        set shape "coin tails"
        set color lime
        set flip 1
        ]
      [
        set shape "coin heads"
        set flip 0
        set color pink
        
      ]
      wait 0.2
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: It will change the coins differently because your random draw is inside the `ask turtles`, so that block of code is run individually for each turtle. There is nothing obviously wrong with this, can you also show the code that calls this procedure?

Comment: Yes, I actually solved it based in what you said. I'll edit the procedure and the correction

Comment: Okay, now you have a different problem - nested `ask turtles`.  Your 'go' procedure asks all turtles to EACH run the procedure called 'tossing', but that procedure also has each turtle actually toss coins.